# How to add rotate option in native image viewer in android devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, rotation, imageview

I am using following code to view the image in native image viewer

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("My path")), "image/*");
con.startActivity(intent);
```

My question is how to **add the rotate option** in the native image viewer.

Comment: No one can help me from this?

Comment: I am still can't get the solution for this can any one help me ?

Comment: Please give me your code, If you can solve.

Comment: Not yet i think android team does not provide such option in the pre loaded image viewer .

Comment: rotating the image before sending it to the image viewer seems to be the only option https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906095/2445763