# How rotate image when open image by Gallery?

Tags: android, android-camera

Capture by My Camera App and Open image by Galerry:
My code open:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();                           
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(dt.FileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Capture by Standard Camera and Open image by Galerry:
[image]

I check Original Image is the same.
How rotate image when open image by Gallery the same Standard Camera?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to change the image orientation

```
          ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
          int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
          ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
          ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

          int rotate = 0;

          switch (exifOrientation) 
        {
          case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
          rotate = 90;
          break; 

         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
         rotate = 180;
         break;

         case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
         rotate = 270;
         break;
         }

           if (rotate != 0) 
        {
          int w = bitmap.getWidth();
          int h = bitmap.getHeight();


          Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
          mtx.preRotate(rotate);

         bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
         bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
       }
```

Comment: Have to save as to other file?

Comment: If use Matrix, i only can set on My control,But i calling android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW of Android.

Comment: you can change orientation of image and store it,then show that image.

Comment: Is Image difference with original image?